# Powers of Piecewise function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the following function `h[x_] = Piecewise[{{1 + x, 1 <= x <= 3}, {13 - 3 x, 3 < x <= 4}} ];`. If you expand it by  `PiecewiseExpand[Composition[h, h][x]]`, thez result although correct is presented in a strange order and some part are very strange -- look the last row:

\begin{cases}
 x+2 & 1\leq x\leq 2 \\
 14-3 x & \frac{10}{3}\leq x\leq 4 \\
 13-3 (x+1) & 2<x\leq 3 \\
 13-3 (13-3 x) & 3<x<\frac{10}{3} \\
 13 & 2<x<\frac{10}{3}
\end{cases}

Is there a way to correct it  and to expand ---~obviously `Expand` doesn't works --- the inside terms as 13 -3(x+1) = 10 - 3x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write

```
simp = ReplacePart[#, 1 -> #[[1, Ordering[N[#[[1, All, 2, 1]]]]]]] &[FullSimplify[#]] &;
simp[PiecewiseExpand[Composition[h, h][x]]]
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  x+2 & 1\leq x\leq 2 \\
>  10-3 x & 2<x\leq 3 \\
>  9 x-26 & 3<x<\frac{10}{3} \\
>  14-3 x & \frac{10}{3}\leq x\leq 4
> \end{cases}$

To rely less on the form of conditions  maybe replace `Ordering[N[#[[1, All, 2, 1]]]]` by
`Ordering[Map[N[Min[Select[Level[#, {-1}], NumericQ]]] &, #[[1, All, 2]]]]`

Answer (score 2):

```
Simplify[Composition[h, h][x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I don't believe the ordering of the conditions makes a difference (apart perhaps from human readability), so there is no point in messing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function that sorts `Piecewise` expressions based on its list of  conditions:

```
toSortedPW = Composition[
   Internal`ToPiecewise @@ # &, 
   #[[All, Ordering[#[[1]]]]] &, 
   Internal`FromPiecewise, 
   Simplify];

toSortedPW @ Composition[h, h][x]
```

[image]

Or, without `` Internal`* `` functions:

```
toSortedPW2 = Composition[
   Piecewise, 
   SortBy[#, Last] &, 
   First, 
   List @@ # &, 
   Simplify]    

toSortedPW2 @ Composition[h, h][x]
```

> same result

Answer (score 0):

```
h[x_] = Piecewise[{{1 + x, 1 <= x <= 3}, {13 - 3 x, 3 < x <= 4}}];

f[x_] = Simplify[Composition[h, h][x]];

ReplacePart[f[x], 1 -> SortBy[f[x][[1]], Last]]
```

[image]